# Link to div inside div within same HTML

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, anchor

I am currently using Bootstrap Timeline ([example here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/timeline-responsive)). Since this will be a long timeline I want at the top of it to have some symbols (each with a date and a unique ID), which will represent certain event. When clicking a certain symbol I want to be redirect to the correspondent event on the timeline.

Nevertheless, at the moment, when I click the symbol I am redirected to the top of the div 'container' which contains the timeline and not to the specific `<li>`

Example:
LINK:

```
<ol class="timeline">
   <li class="timeline__step done">
        <a href="#type1" id="type1"></a>
    </li>

</ol>
```

TO:

```
<div class="container">
     <ul class="timeline2">
        <li id = "type1" onclick = "window.location.hash = 'type1';">
        </li>
     <ul>
<div>`
```

Comment: always make sure your id's are unique on the page or you will get unexpected and weird behaviors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `id` from the link and remove the `onclick` from the timeline item. The hashtag in `href` should jump to the `id` set in the timeline item.

```
<ol class="timeline">
   <li class="timeline__step done">
        <a href="#type1"></a>
    </li>
</ol>

<div class="container">
     <ul class="timeline2">
        <li id="type1">
        </li>
     <ul>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have the same id "type1" for two DOM elements. Id should be unique.